# Django admin inline is not working as describe in docs

Tags: django-admin, django-1.11

I have broker and broker subscription to programs as defined blow. Given the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects), it should be no brainy work to setup program subscription as inline in broker admin view, but its not working as expected. Do I need to add form for inline also ?

```
# Models
class Broker(models.Model):
   ...
   program_subscriptions = models.ManyToManyField(Program, through='ProgramSubscriptions')


class ProgramSubscriptions(models.Model):
    broker = models.ForeignKey(Broker, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    program = models.ForeignKey(Program, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

#Admin
class BrokerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Broker
        fields = ('__all__')

class ProgramSubscriptionsInline(admin.TabularInline):
   model = ProgramSubscriptions
   extra = 0

class BrokerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Broker
    form = BrokerForm
    inlines = (ProgramSubscriptionsInline,)
    exclude = ('program_subscriptions',)

admin.site.register(Broker, BrokerAdmin)
```

Edits:

I dont see anything for program subscription in broker edit view. What I expected was dropdown for each program at-least and list of all program to which broker is subscribed etc ..

Comment: Could it be because of `exclude = ('program_subscriptions',)`?

Comment: Since you're not doing anything fancy with `BrokerForm` I would remove it and not specify any form in `BrokerAdmin`, maybe it's overwriting the inline?